# If H and K are normal subgroups of a group G and $K \leq H$, prove that H/K is normal in G/K (First part of Third Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

My professor offered the following proof. As far as I can see, this proves that H/K is normal in G, not in G/K.  Can somebody help clarify?

Proof:
Let $a \in G$. We want to show $a(H/K)a^{-1} \in H/K.$  Let $hK \in H/K.$ H is normal in G so $\exists h_1 \in H$ such that $ah=h_1a$.  Then we have $ahKa^{-1}=h_1aKa^{-1}=h_1K\in H/K$. So $ahKa^{-1} \in H/K$, because K is normal in G.  Thus, $aH/Ka^{-1} \in H/K$.  Thus, H/K is normal in G/K.

Answer (score 1):

$H/K$ couldn't possibly be normal in $G$, it's not part of $G$ in anyway.